# $\mathcal{G}$ equicontinuous $\implies (g_n)$ equicontinuous?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

If I have a collection of continuous, real valued functions, call this $\mathcal{G}$, and say I have a sequence $(g_n)\in\mathcal{G}$. If I know that $\mathcal{G}$ is equicontinuous, can I conclude that $(g_n)$ is equicontinuous?

My book is leading to me believe that it is true, but I don't understand what it means for a sequence (of functions of course) to be equicontinuous. I thought the term only makes sense where I have a collection of functions, unless I am supposed to view all the images of the sequence as a the collection of functions?

Comment: The collection of *functions* $g_n$ in the sequence is the collection of functions.  That is, we identify $(g_n)$ with the collection $\{g_n: n \in \Bbb N\}$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Thanks for the clarification. One thing I was wondering though, is that by equicontinuity on $\mathcal{F}$, I know that the same $\delta$ in uniform continuity holds for all $f_i\in\mathcal{F}$, but a sequence $(f_n)$ doesn't necessarily have all its terms in $\mathcal{F}$ does it? We don't even know if $\mathcal{F}$ is closed or not, so we can't even say for certain whether the limit of the sequence $f$ is even in $\mathcal{F}$ or not.

Comment: The statement $(f_i) \in \mathcal F$ means that each $f_i$ is in $\mathcal F$. The limit of a sequence is not generally a term of the sequence.